# D3.JS and rCharts: Print doesn't really work

Tags: r, d3.js, shiny, rstudio, rcharts

I would like to print my d3.js charts generated by rCharts. However the print looks like this:

[image]

Any advice how to print the lines correctly? And not just as a big blur...?

Comment: hmm, kinda hard to see, you got a working JSFiddle ?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm quite new to the whole d3.js thing and I have no idea what a JSFiddle is. Everything is correctly displayed when looking at the charts in the browser though.

Comment: its easy, go here : http://jsfiddle.net/ and put your code in the correct areas. Make sure to include reference to D3 in the drop down on the left hand side, will really come in handy when asking questions on here. Your image provided is kind of hard to understand, looks like youve got chart ontop of charts and oversized nodes, would be far easier to help if JSFiddle was provided

Comment: might be that you are styling the big black elements (can't tell if that's a series of circles or a path) via a css external to the script that creates the chart. if you apply the style on the items as you create them in d3 (via the .style or .attr function) they should retain the aspect. this method works with svg crowbar for example